# Finding possible words from list of characters without using character twice

Tags: python

I have a list of characters as follows:

```
letters = "THISORTHAT"
```

I have a list of a large number of words, i.e.

```
dictionary_list = ['AIR', 'AIRS', .. 'TOAST', .. ]
```

I am trying to create a list that contains all of the words in dictionary_list that can be created from the characters in letters[]. The key here is that once I use a character once, I must remove it, i.e. I cannot use a character from letters[] twice. For example, the word 'AIR' is fine, but the word 'ARTHRITIS', is not fine, because 'R' is used twice and 'R' is only present once in letters[], as well as 'I'.

My plan was to divide letters[] into a new list where each character is a new element, and then do the same for each word in dictionary_list[] under a for loop. Then, I came up with the following code. In words, it goes through each word in dictionary_list and if the first letter of the word is found in letters[], then I remove that character from letters[] and repeat for the remainder of the word. If at any time the letter is not found in letters[], this means the word cannot be created and thus the outer loop turns to the next word. If the word can be created, then it is appended to storage.

```
from collections import Counter #for Counter function
letters = 'THISORTHAT'
def split(y):
    return [x for x in y]
storage = [] #where my list of words will go
flag = 1
for i in dictionary_list:
    letters_split = split(letters)
    word = (Counter(i)).keys()
    for j in word:
        if j in letters_split:
            letters_split.remove(j)
            flag = 1
            continue
        else:
            flag = 0
            break
    if flag == 1:
        storage.append(i)
```

The resulting list storage[] contains words such as 'ARTHRITIS', which is not correct according to my problem above. It seems as though the code does not remove the character once it has looped through it, hence as long as the given word contains the same characters, even if it has more of each, it gets appended into my final table. I cannot find the fault in my logic. Does anyone have any tips? Thankyou

Comment: `Counter.keys` will contain each letter just once.  Why not take a `Counter` of `letters` and each dict word and compare the items in each counter dict?

Answer (score 0):

By using the `Counter` function on the word then calling `.keys()` on it, you have made your `word` variable a collection of unique characters in the word. This is not what you want. You can instead iterate through the word as it is.

You can also shorten your code a little more by using the for-else structure

https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/for_-_else.html

```
letters = 'THISORTHAT'
storage = [] 
for i in dictionary_list:
    letters_split = list(letters) #This does the same thing as your split function
    for j in i:
        if j in letters_split:
            letters_split.remove(j)
        else:
            break
    else:
        storage.append(i)
```

Comment: Ah that works! Thankyou. I didn't know you could iterate over characters in a string, I thought you had to convert it into a list of characters. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a dynamic programming problem where you should memoize previous results and prune given the criteria succeeds/fails

Im not sure if I understand completely though. Can the order of letters in the results words be different then the order of the letters in your input list?

I.e

```
Inputchars = “ti”
```

Can a valid word be reverse order

I.e

```
“It”
```

If character order doesn’t need to be preserved and assuming short text i would permute list and solve for word break problem, while accounting for visited characters (discard invalid results at the end)